# Safe way to check if array element exists?

Tags: javascript, arrays, multidimensional-array, null, element

I have a 2D array. 
I currently access that array using notation such as:

`myArray[5][9]` (for example).

What is the *safest way* to check whether or not a certain array element exists?
For example, let's say I am looping through the array and retrieving a property of each array element like so:

`myArray[5][9].firstName`

I then come to `myArray[9][11].firstName` (for example) which doesn't exist. Clearly this will throw an exception as the element doesn't exist.

How can I deal with this? I'm not looping through the entire array (i'm accessing it's contents randomly and say using `myArray.length`in a for loop will not work.

Is there a JS function / method for checking whether or not an array element exists?

Thanks.

Comment: `if (myArray[9][11] !== undefined && 'firstname' in myArray[9][11])`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

like

```
if (!('firstname' in myArray[i][j])) { ... }
```

Answer (score 32):

[Safe call operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Optional_chaining) `?.` looks fine. **Warning**: many, but not all implementations (and versions) of JavaScript supports it.

For your example it will looks like

```js
myArray[5][9]?.firstName
```

**EDIT:** Thanks to [Asaf's](https://stackoverflow.com/users/8104022/asaf) [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28263773/safe-way-to-check-if-array-element-exists#comment114063510_64507315) there is safer version

```js
myArray?.[5]?.[9]?.firstName
```

Comment: This one is bullet proof. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Just check it with `if` condition.

```
if(myArray[i][j].firstName){
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `hasOwnProperty` method to check if an array item exists:

```
if (myArray.hasOwnProperty(x) && myArray[x].hasOwnProperty(y)) {
  var name = myArray[x][y].firstName;
}
```

This checks both dimensions. If you know that the first index (`x` in the example) is always inside the range, you can skip the first test.

If you store some other values in the array also, you would need to check if the item has the `firstName` property:

```
if (myArray.hasOwnProperty(x) && myArray[x].hasOwnProperty(y) && myArray[x][y].hasOwnProperty('firstName')) {
  var name = myArray[x][y].firstName;
}
```